# PIC C18: Converting double to string

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, mplab-c18

I am using PIC18F2550. Programming it with C18 language.
I need a function that converts double to string like below:

```
void dtoa(  char *szString,             // Output string
            double dbDouble,            // Input number
            unsigned char ucFPlaces)    // Number of digits in the resulting fractional part
{
    // ??????????????
}
```

To be called like this in the main program:

```
void main (void)
{
    // ...
    double dbNumber = 123.45678;
    char szText[9];
    dtoa(szText, dbNumber, 3); // szText becomes "123.456" or rounded to "123.457"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sprintf() then find the '.' and null the right decimal character?

Comment: @kenny sprintf() is possibly a bit optomistic on a PIC

Comment: @MartinBeckett I'm sure it's available if you have the space. Or roll your own dtoa()

Comment: "Available" can be a nuanced question since standards like MISRA ban the use of variable arguments...

Comment: I use sprintf all the time on the PIC18, and doubles as well.

Answer (score 1):

So write one!

5mins, a bit of graph paper and a coffee is all it should take.
In fact it's a good interview question

Answer (score 1):

Tiny printf might work for you: http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/index.html

Comment: As mentioned on that page: "Of course being tiny, it has limitations, no floating point support..."

Comment: Ah yes, good catch. Now I dimly recall rolling in our own floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Newlib C library (BSD license, from RedHat, part of Cygwin as well as used in many many "bare-metal" embedded-systems compilers) is a good place to start for usefuls sources for things that would be in the standard C library.

The Newlib `dtoa.c` sources are in the `src/newlib/libc/stdlib` subdirectory of the source tree:

- Online source browser: http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/newlib/libc/stdlib/?cvsroot=src#dirlist
- Direct link to the current version of the `dtoa.c` file: http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/newlib/libc/stdlib/dtoa.c?rev=1.5&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=src

The file is going to be a little odd, in that Newlib uses some odd macros for the function declarations, but should be straightforward to adapt -- and, being BSD-licensed, you can pretty much do whatever you want with it if you keep the copyright notice on it.